# How can I create this abstract sphere in Illustrator (or Sketch)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, abstract

How can I reproduce this cool abstract spherical shape using **Illustrator** (or **Sketch**)???

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? How much do you know of Illustrator and Sketch? It should be far easier to create it in Illustrator, it has better tools for that.

Comment: I've 6 out of 10 experience with Illustration and I'm using Sketch daily. My initial thought was to use the Blend tool, but I'm not sure it's the right way to go ahead.

Comment: Making this in 3d is only several clicks: https://prnt.sc/qltvus

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy is this the 3D tool of Illustrator?

Comment: This is Blender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good day!
You could try this tutorial first:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrsM1RZMtJc

//
And then see my notes below:

1. Make a grid, convert it to symbol.
2. Map that grid/symbol onto the 3D sphere
3. Tweak settings. (choose "No shading" so you only have the "wireframe" (which is actually only the grid we created)) >OK
4. (Sphere still selected). MENU: Object >Expand Appearance.
5. Ungroup it (twice, I think).
6. When you ungroup it enough, the front and back face will still be grouped separately.
7. You may need to draw a circle around the whole thing (to outline the sphere's edge).

//

*My screenshot below. To give you an idea of what I got going on (**Don't mind the different number of grids/wireframes in the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd speheres**) :')*

Kindly come back to us with your results.
[image: My screenshot. To give you an idea of what I got going on :')]

Comment: beat me to it by a minute :)

Comment: Ah, cool man! Still I'm also interested in another workaround.
Because this workaround results in a wireframe that has a "dimension" (not flat/width-less lines).

Comment: On a different note, today is also when I stopped ignoring Illustrator's Symbols :'D because of this tutorial (as workaround for Illustrator not having a Master Page ability): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zORS-HguwR0

Comment: @LorgenGRMagpantay Yse a segmented halfg sphere. Or just a 3d App

Comment: @joojaa at first I thought about a half sphere, but when rotated to show the top it needs a full sphere... perhaps could be done in Blender, there's an SVG exporter there

Comment: @Luciano but off course expiring a mesh is no rocket science. Hell i could do this in notepad and then use acrobat reader as the rendering tool (though illustrator is fine tpp)